# Javascript upload CSV, detect specific keyword, and capture user id if detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ajax

Want to build a simple user interface to upload CSV , detect keyword, and capture user id if keyword is detected. I've looked everywhere and cant find specific example that provides the ability to parse a csv for keyword and capture the UID.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't suppose you could provide an example of the csv?

Comment: Please update the question with your best attempt at coding this yourself. Without it, your question is off-topic on this website, at least in current form. See [ask] for details.